# Obtain Array Entry Using array_keys()

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to obtain the first entry if nothing is set in the `$_POST` or `$_SESSION` but when I output the below using `die(print_r($nmcu));` I always only get 1, if I add numbers to the end of "entry 1" and "exit 2" it seems to work but I'm not sure why, I dont want numbers in the names...

```
<?php
session_start();
$entry = array(
"entry" => array("user" => "username",
        "pass" => "password",
        "host" => "localhost",
        "port" => 1111,
        "protocol" => "http"),

"exit" => array("user" => "username",
        "pass" =>   "password",
        "host" =>   "localhost",
        "port" =>   1111,
        "protocol" => "http"));


if (isset($_POST['currentEntry'])) {
    $_SESSION['currentEntry'] = $_POST['currentEntry'];
}
if (isset($_SESSION['currentEntry'])) {
    $currentEntry = $_SESSION['currentEntry'];
} else {
    $keys = array_keys($entry);
    $currentEntry = $keys[0];
    $_SESSION['currentEntry'] = $currentEntry;
}
$nmcu = $entry[$currentEntry];
?>
```

Comment: Could you explain better what you are trying to do?

Comment: Me couldn't understand what you are trying

Comment: Sorry if it is not clear. I want this code to return the "entry" array if there is nothing being $_POST or in $_SESSION so if you go to the page without any form submit i want it to return the "entry" array details but if they $_POST =entry or =exit then return according array details

Comment: For me your code works just fine (as you expect) - I have tested it on my server.

Comment: When i run it and output the array using print_r($nmcu) i always get the number 1 and no array info.

Comment: You know that `array_keys` only returns the array **key**, not the values, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clean your session (or check it with `var_dump($_SESSION)`. I'm quite sure that you have an invalid key there, so `print_r()` prints nothing and returns `, which is then outputed by`die()`.

Also, I suggest using `var_dump()` instead of `print_r()` for such tests.

Comment: You are correct, i deleted my session and it started working. However when i delete the session and attempt to go to /index.php?currentEntry=exit it still sets entry as the currentEntry so it appears the $_POST is not being read, i have attempted deleting the session and still the same.

Comment: That's a get request, so you should use `$_GET`.